# Nested JSON parsing in react

Tags: json, reactjs, loops

I have following response that I get in `fetch()`

```
{
  "errorCode": "00",
  "errorMsg": "success",
  "roleList": [
    {
      "role_id": 900,
      "roleDescription": "Role_I"
    },
    {
      "role_id": 901,
      "roleDescription": "Role_II"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now i need to get **roleDescription** and render it in , So i tried traversing through the JSON and storing the roleDescription in an array in state.

below is the method written for the same:

```
getroles(e) {
          fetch('http://xyz', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
              "role_id": this.props.location.state.role_id
            })
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
              console.log(`response of getroles: `, responseJson)
              if (responseJson.errorCode === '00') {
                this.setState({roleList : JSON.stringify(responseJson.roleList)});
                let temp = [];
                for (var i=0; i < JSON.stringify(responseJson.roleList).length; i++) {
                  temp.push(JSON.stringify(responseJson.roleList[i].roleDescription))
              }
              }
              else {
               alert("Error Fetching roles" + responseJson.errorMsg);
              }

            })
            .catch((error) => {
             console.error(error);
            });
        }
```

but i am getting error

> Cannot read property 'roleDescription' of undefined

on line `temp.push`

I am very new to react so I am not quite sure if I have the right approach. Please help.

Comment: Can you be more explicit? you need to push the roleDescription for each `roleList` in the temp array?

Comment: @Sabbin  i need to display all the roleDescriptions in a dropdown. So I am trying to extract the roleDesciption from the JSON and store it in an array

Comment: I'll create a fiddle with a much simpler approach if the response below from Matei is not ok for you

Comment: yes,please... that would help..

Comment: remove JSON.stringify. Because it making the array into a string and running up to its length. Use responseJson.roleList.length instead

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee I've added a response, you could check it if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is show your function should look

```
getroles(e) {
    fetch('http://xyz', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "role_id": this.props.location.state.role_id
        })
    })
    .then(async (response) => {
       const responseJson = await response.json();
       if (responseJson.errorCode === '00') {
          const roleList = responseJson.roleList.map((element) => element.roleDescription);
          this.setState({
             roleList
          });
       } else {
          alert("Error Fetching roles" + responseJson.errorMsg);
       }
    })
      .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Here is a working fiddle with the json fetched from an external source [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sabbin/0j1nrL6w/1/)

or you can use it with 2 `then` if you like

```
getroles(e) {
    fetch('http://xyz', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "role_id": this.props.location.state.role_id
        })
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
       if (responseJson.errorCode === '00') {
          const roleList = responseJson.roleList.map((element) => element.roleDescription);
          this.setState({
             roleList
          });
       } else {
          alert("Error Fetching roles" + responseJson.errorMsg);
       }
    })
      .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: i got the roleDescriptions in the temp[] in my state with the help to @Matei but how to populate the dropdown? I am using the `<select><option>{this.state.temp[0]}/</select>` and this renders the first role in the dropdown.but how to bind all the roles from state to <select> ?

Comment: it should be `<select>{this.state.temp.map((element)=>(<option>{element}</option>))}</select>` this is if you have the `temp` set in the `state`

Comment: I've corrected the above comment, now it should be ok

Comment: You're welcome, you could use the `map` function for constructing your `temp` array, it's much cleaner and easy to read instead of the `for`

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use the `JSON.stringify` method at all:

```
getroles(e) {
    fetch('http://xyz', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "role_id": this.props.location.state.role_id
        })
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(`response of getroles: `, responseJson)
        if (responseJson.errorCode === '00') {
            this.setState({roleList : responseJson.roleList});
            let temp = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < responseJson.roleList.length; i++) {
              temp.push(responseJson.roleList[i].roleDescription);
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("Error Fetching roles" + responseJson.errorMsg);
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

I'm wondering why do you receive a list of roles if you query for a single role?

Also, if you decide to set the `temp` variable into the state, it would be better to set both variables `temp` and `roleList` in the same time.

**Later edit:** You don't need to set any temp variable in order to populate a selector with the description of the roles.

```
getroles(e) {
    fetch('http://xyz', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "role_id": this.props.location.state.role_id
        })
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        if (responseJson.errorCode === '00') {
            this.setState({roleList : responseJson.roleList});
        }
        else {
            alert("Error Fetching roles" + responseJson.errorMsg);
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

When you render the selector you should have something like:

```
<select onChange={(event) => alert('Role description for role having id ' + event.value + ' has been selected')}>
    <option value="">Please choose a description</option>
    {this.state.roleList.map((role) => {
         return (
              <option key={role.role_id} value={role.role_id}>
                  {role.roleDescription}
              </option>
         );
    })}
</select>
```

Comment: i am getting a list of roles and i need to display the discriptions in a dropdown

Comment: map it over HTML component of dropdown. i.e this.state.roleList.map(/*return yourhtml component with values /*)

Comment: @Matei I got the roledescription in the temp[] but how to populate the dropdown?

Comment: use the `map` function inside the `render` method in your template

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee just updated my answer to show you how to render the descriptions